# Elements always clearing short item that is floated left

Tags: html, css, css-float

Please look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FnED8/3/

The projects grid items on the right always clear below the `#nav` element on the left once they pass the first row, I want the items on the right to always stay aligned and never clear. Obviously I can set the height of `#nav` to something big like 1000px and get the desired result but this isn't the answer.

Essentially I want `#nav` to be 100% height and `#projects` to respect this and never clear below, always staying beside it.

**Edit** - `#projects` is 90% width to make the grid semi-fluid, this shouldn't affect this problem.

Comment: so you want all the .project divs to be on the right of the #nav and never go to a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to set `display: inline-block` on the `#projects-grid` element. however bear in mind that you will need to adjust the width, because 90% is too wide to fit next to the `#nav`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnED8/5/)

Comment: I've fixed it now - this pointed me in the right direction though. I didn't make my question especially clear though! 90% was too wide for #projects-grid to fit, once I set it to 80%  and floated left all worked as it should. I really shouldn't have needed help with that but thanks anyway all!

Answer (score 2):

Make your projects-grid like this:-

```
#projects-grid {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FnED8/4/

Or whatever width you prefer.
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/FnED8/7/

Setting a proper left margin for `#projects` grid and removing its width of 90% does it.

```
#projects-grid {
    margin-left: 174px;
}
```

Comment: yea but i wanted #projects-grid to have a % width so as to expand to fill larger screens

Comment: It also expands like this - check it!